# Pointer to array of structures as JNA method arguments

Tags: java, c, jna

I am trying to create a JNA implementation over the [SctpDrv](http://www.bluestop.org/SctpDrv/) library. My problem is that I don't get my head around pointers to structure arrays. I have tried to search for a solution, but they have always been slightly different from what I need to know. The JNA dokumentation only show an example with a pointer to an array of primitive type. There also seem to be different ways of doing this, of which some are depricated.

```
int  WSAAPI internal_sctp_getpaddrs (SOCKET, sctp_assoc_t, struct sockaddr **);
void WSAAPI internal_sctp_freepaddrs (struct sockaddr *);
```

According to the documentation the third argument of getpaddrs is used to return an array of `sockaddr` structures. What is the recommended way to declare the corresponding JNA methods, and how do I prepare the argument, as well as get access to it after the call in my java code?

Also, to help me understand, how would I declare and use a function where instead the argument is an array containing pointers?

Comment: Does http://jna.java.net/#structures help a bit?

Answer (score 5):

```
// Declare the SOCKADDR struct
public class SOCKADDR extends Structure
{
   // Declare fields here

   public SOCKADDR()
   {
      // required for toArray()
   }

   public SOCKADDR(Pointer pointer)
   {
      super(pointer);
   }
}

// Declare these Java methods to be mapped by JNA to the C APIs
public int  internal_sctp_getpaddrs(int socket, int sctp, PointerByReference sockaddrRef);
public void internal_sctp_freepaddrs(SOCKADDR sockaddr);

// Use this code to call internal_sctp_getpaddrs()
// This code assumes the number of SOCKADDRs returned is in the int return value.
{
   PointerByReference sockaddrRef;
   Pointer pointer;
   SOCKADDR sockaddr, sockaddrs[];
   int size;

   sockaddrRef = new PointerByReference();
   size        = internal_sctp_getpaddrs(socket, sctp, sockaddrRef);
   pointer     = sockaddrRef.getValue();
   sockaddr    = new SOCKADDR(pointer);
   sockaddrs   = (SOCKADDR[]) sockaddr.toArray(size);
}
```